# Invalid ViewState after a-sync postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, viewstate, jquery-tabs

I'm having a problem with an UpdatePanel. When a user clicks a button inside the panel, I get an async PostBack and a set of jQuery tabs is reinitialized. If (after the successful first async postback) I try to use a button or other control outside the UpdatePanel, I get the following error:

```
An error has occured on page: http://server/details.aspx for user:  at IP: 192.168.0.92
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.    at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)
   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.details_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 192.168.0.92
    Port: 1707
    Referer: http://server/details.aspx
    Path: /server/details.aspx
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
    ViewState: /wEPDwULLTEwMTkxMjEwNTNkZBSW/poBumnzl2Hp6YECMfZitwnKh80rC7JEaLc28HAh,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... 
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.     at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
```

I'm not really sure how to go about troubleshooting this, everything else inside the updatepanel on different tabs seems to work.

Comment: Do you have some HttpModule modifying ViewState or the page? Maybe a compression module?

Comment: Can you create a *minimal* working example that reliably reproduces the problem?

Comment: It's heavily tied into my intranet sorry, but there are no modules intercepting anything.

Answer (score 1):

it could happen for few reasons.

Foremost is that your Ajax controls on refresh is creating its own viewstate which replaces main page viewstate.

There are some solutions I read on other forums like adding

```
             Response.End
```

after the Ajax output. You may need to handle ThreadAbortException when you use Response.End

Second suggested way by another user is taking off Runat from Ajax form element.

It can also happen when the Ajax postback url is going to a separate page to grab the data. If that is the case you might want to change the url to the same page.

Comment: Oddly, it's actually a button which sends an email then toggle's an asp:Label's visible property.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you creating on the fly new controls which has a form which has a viewstate and thats why  ...?